# How to get base from existing sql DDL file?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy for MySQL.

The common example of SQLAlchemy is

1. Defining model classes by the table structure.  (`class User(Base)`)
2. Migrate to the database by `db.create_all` (or alembic, etc)
3. Import the model class, and use it. (`db.session.query(User)`)

But what if I want to use raw SQL file instead of defined model classes?
I did read `automap` do similar like this, but I want to get mapper object from raw SQL file, not created database.

Is there any best practice to do this?

This is an example of DDL

```sql
-- ddl.sql
-- This is just an example, so please ignore some issues related to a grammar
CREATE TABLE `card` (
  `card_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'card',
  `card_company_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'card_company_id',
  PRIMARY KEY (`card_id`),
  KEY `card_ix01` (`card_company_id`),
  KEY `card_ix02` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COMMENT='card table'
```

And I want to do like

```
Base = raw_sql_base('ddl.sql')  # Some kinda automap_base but from SQL file

# engine, suppose it has two tables 'user' and 'address' set up
engine = create_engine("mysql://user@localhost/program")

# reflect the tables
Base.prepare(engine)

# mapped classes are now created with names by sql file
Card = Base.classes.card

session = Session(engine)

session.add(Card(card_id=1, card_company_id=1))
session.commit()  # Insert
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLAlchemy is not an SQL *parser*, but the exact opposite; its reflection works against existing databases only. In other words you must execute your DDL and then use reflection / automap to create the necessary Python models:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base

# engine, suppose it has two tables 'user' and 'address' set up
engine = create_engine("mysql://user@localhost/program")

# execute the DDL in order to populate the DB
with open('ddl.sql') as ddl:
    engine.execute(ddl)

Base = automap_base()

# reflect the tables
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)

# mapped classes are now created with names by sql file
Card = Base.classes.card

session = Session(engine)

session.add(Card(card_id=1, card_company_id=1))
session.commit()  # Insert
```

This of course may fail, if you have already executed the same DDL against your database, so you would have to handle that case as well. Another possible caveat is that some DB-API drivers may not like executing multiple statements at a time, if your `ddl.sql` happens to contain more than one `CREATE TABLE` statement etc.

> ...but I want to get mapper object from raw SQL file.

Ok, in that case what you need is the aforementioned *parser*. A cursory search produced two candidates:

- [sqlparse](https://pypi.org/project/sqlparse/): Generic, but the [issue tracker](https://github.com/andialbrecht/sqlparse/issues) is a testament to how nontrivial parsing SQL is. Is often confused, for example parses `` ... COMMENT 'card', `card_company_id` ... `` as a keyword and an identifier list, not as a keyword, a literal, punctuation, and an identifier (or even better, the column definitions as their own nodes).
- [mysqlparse](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlparse/): A MySQL specific solution, but with limited support for just about anything, and it seems abandoned.

Parsing would be just the first step, though. You'd then have to convert the resulting trees to models.